# How to separate a shape from itself in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I have a single shape in PhotoShop, and I need to detach the shape from itself without affecting the rest of the shape. No matter how many anchor points I add, I still can't get it to separate while remaining one shape.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD.SE. The question is unclear (and the question is about the get closed because of this), what exactly do you want to separate.  please edit the question so its understandable.

Comment: I added more detail and pictures now to help explain what I am trying to do

Comment: In general, you use the Direct Selection tool and the Pen tool to remove portions of paths and then click anchors to reconnect where you've removed pieces. It's fairly impossible to give exact direction without seeing *the actual paths and anchors* of the shape. The letter notations are no help.

Comment: Do you want to make them separate shape layers? ...separate them within that one shape layer? ...or maybe you just want to get rid of one of them?

Comment: Okay I changed the image again to a simpler image that shows what I am trying to do better

Comment: A better software for this is Illustrator. Otherwise read about how to use the pen tool: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html#add_or_delete_anchor_points You need to add some anchor points, delete some, and re-attach some to create that effect. It's basic vector work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you just need to subtract another shape.

[image]

Add or draw a shape in the same shape layer and subtract it from the front. So it goes from something like this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

If you want you can then use that little menu again and Merge Shape Components to leave you with a single shape again.